# Build boost library with specific name

Tags: c++, boost, build

I am trying to compile my program, which uses boost library, with MSVC 2013 and I get link error:

> Cannot open input file boost_iostreams-vc120-1.57.lib

I already built boost successfully a few times with many combinations of options (for example "bjam toolset=msvc --build-type=complete"), but I don't have boost_iostreams-vc120-1.57.lib in my stage directory. I have there libraries with names libboost_iostreams.lib, libboost_iostreams-vc-120-mt-1_57.lib and others. Also I don't want to change any settings in MSVC, because my project was generated by CMake.

So the question is: How do I build library boost_iostreams-vc120-1.57.lib with Windows?

Thanks for answers and sorry for my english

Comment: I know that is not your question, but as a side note you should be able to tell CMake to look for Boost libraries without multi-threading by setting `set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED OFF)` before calling `find_package(Boost...)`; that way it should look for your existing libraries.

Comment: Also not answering your question, but note that you can use `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` and just include the boost source files that you need in your main project for compilation.

Answer (score 1):

`-mt` suffix means build with multithreading support that is always on for MSVC. Single threaded CRT was dropped in VS 2008 or even 2005, so both your code and boost will be multithreading aware anyway. If you don't want to change your build config you can simply remove "-mt" suffix from libraries names. But since boost has MSVC autolink support (`#pragma comment (lib, "...")` in header files) it may be better to make an exception for MSVC and not to link to boost libraries manually at all.